# MIME "From:" header with national characters

Tags: header, mime, chilkat

What is the correct format of "From:" header when From Name contains national characters and dot (.) character?

We generate (using C# Chilkat lib) this:

```
From: =?utf-8?Q?Micha=C5=82_from_domain.com?= <abcdef@domain.com>
```

(where From Name = Michał from domain.com)

This works OK in most cases. However, we encountered an email provider which marks this header as invalid and uses Return-Path header instead (which is machine-readable only).

The error is:

```
Illegal-Object: Syntax error in From: address found on ps11.m5r2.onet: 
From: =?utf-8?Q?Micha=C5=82_from_domain.com?=<abcdef@domain.com>
^-missing end of mailbox
```

The provider insists the the problem is the lack of space between name and email. This is not the case on our end (see previous code example).

Answer (score 0):

That email provider has a broken MTA.  Unfortunately, you have to deal with it.

You're already formatting your non-ASCII "From" personal-part as an RFC 2047 encoded-word.  Since you're using `Q` as the encoding, you can take advantage of the flexibility in the quoted-printable encoding and encode the `.` as well:

```
From: =?utf-8?Q?Micha=C5=82_from_domain=2Ecom?= <abcdef@domain.com>
```

(Note that the `.` has been replaced by its quoted-printable encoding, `=2E`.)